# Мобильная версия сайта выглядит ужасно на Honor 9

Tags: веб-дизайн

Мобильная версия сайта нормально отображается в инспекторе и на телефоне (iphone 5 - 8) а на телефоне Honor 9 выглядит просто ужасно.

Сталкивался кто-нибудь с таким? Где можно онлайн эмулировать Honor 9 для мобильной разработки?

Comment: В чём именно ужас?

Comment: Вот сайт - http://testdomain.agrovit-bio.ru/, а на Honor он выглядит так:http://joxi.ru/82QBBwgCjjM55A

Comment: может быть с viewport проблемы? попробуйте вместо minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0 прописать initial-scale=1

Comment: Сейчас попробую, но так как у меня медиазапросы. Судя по картинкам - возможно браузер того телефона не понимает display: flex;

Comment: Хотя там и скрипты не работают, стили не подтягиваются... очень странно.